# How to clone a project and stay tuned with new updates

Tags: github

I want to clone `POX Controller` from `Github` repository into my laptop. The only way I know is by cloning. However, I think if someone clone a project, he/she won't get the updates that the others have done in it. I have read about `forking` but I don't really understand the difference between `fork` and `clone`. So how do I get a project from Github and still be able to receive updates?

Thank you.

Comment: Clone it once (which you have already done), then do `git fetch` periodically to stay updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clone a repository means that you will download the whole code of the repository to your laptop.

A *fork* is a copy of a repository. Forking a repository allows you to freely experiment with changes without affecting the original project.

Most commonly, forks are used to either propose changes to someone else's project or to use someone else's project as a starting point for your own idea. More at [Fork A Repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/).

as @TimBiegeleisen says, you can get the project and stay updated by clone once then `git fetch` it periodically.

For example, if you want to cloning [POX Controller](http://www.noxrepo.org/), clone it:

```
git clone https://github.com/noxrepo/pox
```

Then to update it, do the following command on your cloned project:

```
cd pox // go to your clone project
git fetch
```

Or you can use `git pull` instead of `git fetch` if only need to stay update without keeping your change in the cloned project.

But you must remember the difference between `git fetch` and `git pull`. @GregHewgill [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292359/4758255) explain it in details:

> In the simplest terms, `git pull` does a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`.
>   You can do a `git fetch` at any time to update your remote-tracking branches under `refs/remotes/<remote>/`. This operation never changes any of your own local branches under `refs/heads`, and is safe to do without changing your working copy. I have even heard of people running `git fetch` periodically in a cron job in the background (although I wouldn't recommend doing this).
>
> A `git pull` is what you would do to bring a local branch up-to-date with its remote version, while also updating your other remote-tracking branches.
>
> Git documentation: [git pull](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)